# Getting the compiled asm of .NET application in Mono

Tags: .net, assembly, mono, clr, jit

Can I get asm-implementation of .NET application after JIT-compilation in Mono 3.2.3 (namely assembler, not IL). In Visual Studio I can use different debug tools for getting asm-code, registers state, memory, etc. :
[image: VisualStudioScreenshot]

Is there some way to get this data in Mono? Can I also get dump of memory in runtime? Previously, for these purposes, I could use [Hard debugger](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide:Debugger), but it's not supported now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run with:

```
mono -v -v yourprogram.exe
```

This will dump lots of info about jit compilation, including the assembly code.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile with AOT in Mono, which achieves the equivalent. Not sure about debugging this binary in an IDE though.